# Existing Algorithm / Code to calculate exact values of the Riemann Zeta function at even natural numbers?

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, analytic-number-theory, computational-mathematics, symbolic-computation

I wanted to know if there's any existing algorithm to compute exact values of the Riemann Zeta function at even natural numbers? For example, it should compute $\zeta(4)$ as exactly $\frac{\pi^4}{90}$ i.e.in fraction form, not a decimal approximation.

If there is such an algorithm, could you state its complexity as well? Similarly, is there an algorithm to calculate the values of the Dirichlet Beta function at odd natural numbers?

Comment: there is an exact formula using bernouli numbers [here](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/bernoullizeta.pdf). So do you mean time complexity of calculating bernouli numbers

Comment: Equivalently to the Bernoulli number method (and though I don't quite remember all the details), one can get these values by finding the coefficients of some Laurent series involving tangent and sine functions. It should be easy enough to  write a program to pull out the necessary information, as one can do it by hand for the values of $2,4,6,8$ easy enough. (I'm sure someone here remembers this method of calculating $\zeta(2)$ - if not, it's probably been answered here before.)

Comment: @user129901 You mean in terms of fractions? Not a decimal approximation for the Bernoulli numbers, right? If yes, then what's the complexity?

Comment: You can compute a single $B_n$ with $O(n^{\frac{4}{3}+o(1)})$ bit operations, see
the David Harvey's page http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~davidharvey/ and his talk  _Old and new algorithms for computing Bernoulli numbers_ (available as http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~davidharvey/talks/bernoulli.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @mixedmath's comment: just invert the matrix $P_n$ of the size $nxn$, for example $n=6$
$$ P_n =P_6 = \small \left[ \begin{array} {} 
 1 & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 1 & 2 & . & . & . & . \\ 
 1 & 3 & 3 & . & . & . \\ 
 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & . & . \\ 
 1 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 5 & . \\ 
 1 & 6 & 15 & 20 & 15 & 6
\end{array} \right] $$
which is simply a submatrix of the Patscalmatrix reduced by the diagonal. You get
$$ G_6=P_6^{-1} =\small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 -1/2 & 1/2 & . & . & . & . \\ 
 1/6 & -1/2 & 1/3 & . & . & . \\ 
 0 & 1/4 & -1/2 & 1/4 & . & . \\ 
 -1/30 & 0 & 1/3 & -1/2 & 1/5 & . \\ 
 0 & -1/12 & 0 & 5/12 & -1/2 & 1/6
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and in the first column you'll find the Bernoulli-numbers. You can do this for any size $n$. Becasue the matrix is triangular, the inversion is really a simple task.
After you have the Bernoulli-numbers, you can express the zetas at even indexes by the well known conversion formula (due to L. Euler) as rational multiple of powers of $\pi$

Answer (score 1):

The value is known to be:
$$
\zeta(2 k) = \frac{(-1)^{k + 1} 4^k \pi^{2 k} B_{2 k}}{2 (2 k)!}
$$
The [Bernoulli numbers page](http://bernoulli.org) probably has the best algorithms to compute the $B_{2 k}$.